Use format specifier to convert float/int column in polars dataframe to string
I have this code:
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({'size': [34.2399, 1232.22, -479.1]})
df.with_columns(pl.format('{:,.2f}', pl.col('size')))

But is fails:
ValueError - Traceback, line 3
      2 df = pl.DataFrame({'size': [34.2399, 1232.22, -479.1]})
----> 3 df.with_columns(pl.format('{:,.2f}', pl.col('size')))

File polars\functions\as_datatype.py:718, in format(f_string, *args)
    717     msg = "number of placeholders should equal the number of arguments"
--> 718     raise ValueError(msg)

ValueError: number of placeholders should equal the number of arguments

How can I format a float or int column using a format specifier like '{:,.2f}'?

The feature request about this, just for reference: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7133

As outlined by @mozway, general format strings are not yet supported as part of pl.format. The corresponding feature request already contains a nice polars implementation of (the most common) C-style sprint formatting.
If efficiency is not too much of an issue (e.g. in exploratory data analysis), you can simply use pl.Expr.map_elements and fall back to the naive python solution.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("size").map_elements(lambda x: f"{x:,.2f}", return_dtype=pl.String)
)

shape: (3, 1)
┌──────────┐
│ size     │
│ ---      │
│ str      │
╞══════════╡
│ 34.24    │
│ 1,232.22 │
│ -479.10  │
└──────────┘


For the time-being, I opted for this one, though I used a slightly tweaked version: pl.col('size').map_elements('{:,.2f}'.format, return_dtype=pl.String).

pl.format is recognizing literal {}, unlike python's f-strings (if you run df.with_columns(pl.format('{:,.2f}')) you'll see that {:,.2f} is left unchanged).
Thus you can't use pl.format the way you want (as posted as comment to the question, this is a feature request).
You might want to use one of the methods described here instead.
Code of pl.format that shows how it works, it simply splits the strings on {} (f_string.split("{}")) and joins it back with the expressions in between:
def format(f_string: str, *args: Expr | str) -> Expr:
    if f_string.count("{}") != len(args):
        msg = "number of placeholders should equal the number of arguments"
        raise ValueError(msg)

    exprs = []

    arguments = iter(args)
    for i, s in enumerate(f_string.split("{}")):
        if i > 0:
            e = wrap_expr(parse_into_expression(next(arguments)))
            exprs.append(e)

        if len(s) > 0:
            exprs.append(F.lit(s))

    return concat_str(exprs, separator="")

